# Is it possible to have airflow backfill and scheduling at the same time?

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I am in a situation where I have started getting some data scheduled daily at a certain time and I have to create ETL for that data.

Meanwhile, when I am still creating the DAGs for scheduling the tasks in Airflow. The data keeps on arriving daily. So when I will start running my DAGs from today I want to schedule it daily and also wants to backfill all the data from past days which I missed while I was creating DAGs.

I know that if I put start_date as the date from which the data started arriving airflow will start backfilling from that date, but wouldn't in that case, my DAGs will always be behind of current day? How can I achieve backfilling and scheduling at the same time? Do I need to create separate DAGs/tasks for backfill and scheduling?

Answer (score 1):

There are several things you need to consider.
1. Is your daily data independent or the next run is dependent on the previous run?

If the data is dependent on previous state you can run backfill in Airflow.

How backfilling works in Airflow ?
Airflow gives you the facility to run past DAGs. The process of running past DAGs is called Backfill. The process of Backfill actually let Airflow forset some status of all DAGs since it’s inception.

> I know that if I put start_date as the date from which the data
>   started arriving airflow will start backfilling from that date, but
>   wouldn't in that case, my DAGs will always be behind of current day?

Yes setting a past start_date is the correct way of backfilling in airflow.
No, If you use celery executer, the jobs will be running in parallel and it will eventually catch up to the current day , obviously depending upon your execution duration.

> How can I achieve backfilling and scheduling at the same time? Do I
>   need to create separate DAGs/tasks for backfill and scheduling?

You do not need to do anything extra to achieve scheduling and backfilling at the same time, Airflow will take care of both depending on your `start_date`

Finally , If this activity is going to be one time task I recommend , you process your data(manually) offline to airflow , this will give you more control over the execution.
and then either mark the backfilled tasks as succeed or below

1. Run an airflow backfill command like this: `airflow backfill -m -s "2016-12-10 12:00" -e "2016-12-10 14:00" users_etl`.

This command will create task instances for all schedule from 12:00 PM to 02:00 PM and mark it as success without executing the task at all. Ensure that you set your `depends_on_past` config to `False`, it will make this process a lot faster. When you’re done with it, set it back to `True`.

**Or**

2. Even simpler set the `start_date` to current date